# MeteorJS - access to helpers of the same template

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, helper

I'm working on a first project in meteor and I have trivial problem (I suppose it is easy to do) but I can't find proper way to do it right. This is simplified code in which I want to push some object to helper array.

```
Template.courses.helpers({
    doneCourses: [],
    init: function(){
        doneCourses.push({ title: this.name, date: this.endDate });      
    }
});
```

Unfortunatey i have error: "Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: doneCourses is not defined..". What is the proper way to do it? I want to show doneCourses on HTML with

```
{{ #each doneCourses }}
```

but I have to get it from database on the beginning. Additional question - what is the best way to do init functions? Do it in iron router data field or make separate init function?

Comment: Can you say more about what you are trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doneCourse: function () { ... }
```

is the correct way to do things.

If you need to do stuff when the template is rendered or created you can use `onRendered` or `onCreated` that Template supplies.